# Constructing a view of tables with different columns and column length

Tags: sql-server

Is is possible to create a view of 2 or more tables with different columns and column length. I am using MS SQL.

For example I have below tables and column structure

```
USAAddress (door no, street char(30), city, zipcode (50))
GBPAddress (door no, addressline1 char(30), addressline2 char(30), 
addressline3 city, country, postcode char(30), phoneno char(30))
```

Would it be possible to create a view of the above two tables with different columns and data type sizes?

```
i) street would be mapped to addressline1
ii) zipcode would be mapped to postcode (zipcode is char(50) while postcode is char(30))
iii)phoneno is missing in USAAddress table, while it is present in GBPAddress table. I view should have phoneno but should show as empty in USAAddress.
```

Comment: Have you tried? Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using a query like below in the view should do the trick :

```
select addressline1, postcode, phoneno
from GBPAddress

union all

select street, left(zipcode,30), null 
from USAAddress
```

As a sidenote, it's more common to use VARCHAR for long text fields where the length varies.  Instead of using CHAR for when the length of the data is rather fixed.